# NodeJS Can you redirect a GET request to a POST request?

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to redirect an incoming GET request to a POST one in nodeJS?

For example:

1. I have a GET '/reset' incoming request
2. I need to make a POST '/clear' request as a result and pass in an id

Is this possible after detecting the route using app.get()?

Comment: Sure you can. Once your server is processing a request, you can make literally anything with it, including making other, unrelated requests or any kind of process.

Comment: I am feeling you are doing something wrong with you structure. why dont you make "clear" api function as util and call that function instead of thinking about http redirect?

Comment: What would be the proper format? I would like to do something like the following, but the post doesn't seem to trigger so I know my syntax is off..


`this.app.get('/reset/', (req, res) => {
    this.app.post('/clear/');
}`

Answer (score 0):

I solved by redirecting the route to a route in my api spa which then called a post.